# atmega328p for loop coding

Tags: c, atmega

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


int main()
{
    DDRD = 0x05;
    PORTD=0xFF;
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    int state=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(!(PIND &(1<<5)) && (state==0))
        {

            state=1;

                PORTB = 0x38;
                for(int i=0;i<=199;i++)
                {
                    T1Delay_1s();
                }
                PORTB=0x00;
                for(int i=0;i<=199;i++)
                {
                    T1Delay_1s();
                }
        }

        if(!(PIND &(1<<5)) && (state==1))
        {
            state=0;
            PORTB = 0x08;
            for(int i=0;i<=99;i++)
            {
                T1Delay_1s();
            }
            PORTB=0x30;
            for(int i=0;i<=99;i++)
            {
                T1Delay_1s();
            }
        }
    }
}

void T1Delay_1s()
{
    TCNT0=156;
    TCCR0B=0x05;
    while((TIFR0&(1<<TOV0))==0);
    TCCR0B=0;
    TIFR0=0x1<<TOV0;
}
```

The question is required that the LEDs connected to `PB3`,`PB4`,`PB5` are turned on 
in `state0(PB3=1,PB4=1,PB5=1)` and then all turn off(000) every 2 seconds

(`111->000` every 2 seconds)

if the button is pressed, the LEDs connected to `PB3`,`PB4`,`PB5` are turned on in `state1`(100) and then change to(011) every second

(`100->011` every second)

The effect of switching is fine, but the blinking effect is missed, the LEDs will blink for one loop only and then stop,how should I to fix the problem?

Comment: What happens if you keep the button pressed? I guess you will get your desired output. If so, then you need to change the logic in `if` statement.

Comment: What is PIND? Does your program enter the if-blocks in the 2nd loop?

Comment: `PIND` is the hardware register to read the state of the port pins of microcontroller.

Comment: I can do it if I keep the button pressed, but my expected result is just press the button once and then change state.

Comment: Buttons cannot be read this way.